# Neo4J Database Performance

Tags: neo4j

We have a Neo4J database (running on Enterprise version 4.3.2) that contains:

6,800,000 nodes with label `itemA`.
25,000 nodes with label `itemB`.
18 nodes with label `itemC`.

Each node with label `itemA` is related to at least one node with label `itemB` through a relationship called `a_b`.

Each node with label `itemA` is related to at least one node with label `itemC` through a relationship called `a_c`.

There are 7,000,000 `a_b` relationships.
There are 7,000,000 `a_c` relationships.

Nodes with label `itemA` have a property `prop1` that contains one of 3 string values - each of which is approximately 20 characters in length. `prop1` is indexed.

The following queries and their results:

| Query | Duration(ms) |
| --- | --- |
| `match (a:itemA) return count(a)` | 1 |
| `match (b:itemB) return count(b)` | 1 |
| `match (a:itemA)-[r:a_b]->(b:itemB) count(a)` | 1,800-2,200 |
| `match (a:itemA)-[r:a_b]->(b:itemB) return a.prop1, count(a)` | 10,500-14,000 |
| `match (a:itemA)-[r:a_b]->(b:itemB), (a)-[r2:a_c]->(c:itemC) return count(a)` | 14,500 |
| `match (a:itemA)-[r:a_b]->(b:itemB), (a)-[r2:a_c]->(c:itemC) return a.prop1, count(a)` | > 20,000 |

We have consulted with support team at Neo4J. We are happy that our server has adequate resource and that Neo4J database server is configured correctly.

My question:

Should queries on this scale really be this slow? If not, what are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third and fourth queries could be optimized as your are only counting node degree:

Third query:

```
match (a:itemA)
WITH a,size((a)-[:a_b]->()) as degree
RETURN sum(degree) as result
```

Fourth query:

```
match (a:itemA) return a.prop1, size((a)-[:a_b]->())
```

fifth and six query are going to explode no matter what because you are counting the co-occurences and you likely get big numbers as result. You can use the `PROFILE` clause to inspect what is going on under the hood.

Comment: for the fifth and sixth query you could perhaps just multiply node degrees

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I try to use `size()`, I get a message from Neo that this feature is deprecated and will be removed in later versions.
Also, when I ran the query using `size()`, the query was running for over 5 minutes before I killed it. I think this is an anti-solution.

Profile doesn't really help. It just says that there are millions of DB hits, which I would expect. You raise a good point about queries 5 and 6. Would you imagine they have better performance as `(c)<-[a_c]-(a)-[a_b]->(b)`?

Comment: take a look at https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/fast-counts-using-the-count-store/

Comment: Thanks - will take a look, but the main issue isn't the count - it's property access. Take query 4, for example, it's 7 times slower than the preceding query. Seems a bit much.

Comment: not much you can do there if you are aggregating by property.

Comment: Ahh. That's what I was expecting, but not what I was hoping for :D Thanks for taking the time to answer.